# Regex for graphQl not returning results when added to react component

Tags: reactjs, regex, graphql, graphql-js, graphiql

I was testing queries out with GraphiQl explorer, which returned the results I wanted using the a regular expression underlined in red below.

[image]

You can see it returns results and it generates the code for react in the far right of the screenshot. I was hopeful that it would work straight away with a copy & paste but apparently you have to escape the regex in the template literal string (**Why doesn't the code explorer do that if you need to escape it anyway?**)

Below are the results if you try to add the code the way its generated.

[image]

Through some googling & a GitHub issue I found that the regex needs to be double escaped.
See the update for the fix below. [Link to regex PR](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/pull/26592)

[image]

Added the change to my regex and it stopped the previous error.
But now its not showing any results..

Regex updated ->

[image]

No results ->

[image]

I've tried using variables to inject the original regex to the template literal string but no avail as apparently you can't do that with graphQl. Has anyone had this issue or care to share an idea/solution ?

Comment: Nothing special about regexes, but you got backslashes inside a (`gql`) template string which you need to escape. Yes, using a variable would be much simpler than specifying a string literal in the query string.

Comment: @Bergi I thought the PR they did was escaping the backslashes. Would you know a way around this without using a variable as it doesn't allow string interpolation

Comment: No, the PR you link did fix the code that unnecessarily was *removing* the escaping. The code really just is trimming the `/` from the string and passing it to the `RegExp` constructor, like `new RegExp("\\d")` is equivalent to `/\d/`.

Comment: What do you mean by "*it doesn't allow string interpolation*"?

Comment: Btw, using `regex: ${ JSON.stringify(/\d-\/\d/.toString()) }` should work

Comment: @Bergi Trying that line of code you suggested I get ""BabelPluginRemoveGraphQLQueries: String interpolations are not allowed in graphql fragments." Think I'm going to have to use a different graphQl query designer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew There are no regex literals in GraphQL

Comment: @Paddymac Ah, if your `gql` babel plugin doesn't support interpolation (not even of constant expressions), then you need to write `gql\`… regex: "/\\\\d-\\\\/\\\\d/\" …\``. Or just use a variable - there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: "*Why doesn't the code explorer do that if you need to escape it anyway?*" - that appears to be a bug in the code explorer. Since it does display a template literal, it should properly escape any backslashes in the template contents. Please report this issue.